Why does batch file run properly in program folder, but not within a batch file pointing to correct path
I setup a batch file in the same directory as the program it launches and it works properly with the switches.
But the same program will not properly run when called for in batch file located outside of the program, but with the path specified within it.
Does there need to be another entry in the batch file like a set command?
@echo off
cd /d "L:\Movies" || exit
"D:\MC\mc_com.exe" -m -p Process 

The batch file points to Media Companion (application to scrape media files which along with the switches, renames the mpg files, pulls down graphics and the puts it all a folder of the same name).
The batch file hosted inside the Media Companion directory works correctly. Outside of it as the path is above, it flounders with scraping the data properly.

A workaround, not an answer: leave the batch file in the same directory as the app, and make a shortcut to the batch file that can be called anywhere. That has the advantages of making the shortcut run Minimized (i.e., hidden), or as Admin, if you wish, as well as allowing the path in the batch file to be relative, not full path, so the whole folder can be moved eslewhere.

Can you share the batch, and perhaps some details on the application? Please EDIT your post to add this information.

@echo off

pushd "D:\MC" || exit
mc_com.exe -m -p Process

popd


A little bit of explanation regarding the problem and how this solves it would help make this a better answer.

Worked like a charm! Thank you all!

@music2myear Hi, I agree, the priority was to provide help, but in these festive days, without much time, in the future I will post details, in the form that you have already seen in my posts.
